# How to implement Erlang's "Let it crash" concept in java

Tags: java, crash, erlang, actor

I have been searching for any simple example on ths concept / design pattern / what ever it is called, i want to see any simple example in java, i want to know if it is possible to apply this concept in an android application or not, i'm already using actor model in android  but i want to apply the "Let it crash" pattern to it, where can i find any java examples or explanations for it ... I always see high level discussions with no code in it or even UMLs

I tried nothing since i cant imagine how it is done !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a way of doing this for several years (2003-2009) in Java. Then I found out how Erlang works and has been coding Erlang since then. If I have to code Java ever again I will use this pattern for sure.

The way I did it in Java for some major website projects was this:

1. Avoid try-catch blocks when you can. Let the code crash on NullPointerExceptions and similar subclasses of RuntimeExceptions.
2. All Exceptions that inherit from RuntimeException are "OK" and will produce crashes in runtime. Just make sure they are logged (on a server) or handled somehow (in a client). Do this default crash handling at one central place to avoid code duplication.
3. Sometimes you are forced by the Java compiler to handle a catched Exception. Then just rethrow the catched Exception inside a RuntimeException.

Here is a classic example of catching the checked exception java.sql.SQLException that the compiler forces you to handle and retrowing is as a RuntimeException.

```html
try {
  your code here...
} catch (SQLException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

This works like a charm. The complete stacktrace is kept and no information is lost. The compiler is happy and you are happy since you have transformed a Java checked exception into a RuntimeException.

4. All Exceptions you define yourself and all Exceptions you throw in your code explicitly should inherit from java.lang.RuntimeException.

Good luck!

This error handling approach made my Java codebase so much smaller and it did become "Let it crash". Not perfect, but a lot better.

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply, so you mean that i will not handle any exceptions except in the default uncaught exceptions handler for example, but this means that i will restart the whole object/actor when it crashes ... What about it's state, assume that an actor crashed while parsing a response from server, how is this handled?

Comment: I mean if i restart the actor, it will keep crashing every time this request is done ! ... Where can i find some sources about how erlang handles this ?

Comment: The erlang way of handling restart logic for crashing processes is done with a supervisor or a supervisor hierarchy. This is very cool stuff for handling infinite crash loops in some smart controlled way. If you have something crashing over and over (like your actor) the supervisor logic can be configured to allow X number of restarts and then the supervisor will give up and crash instead. 

More info here about Erlang supervisors and how cool they are: http://learnyousomeerlang.com/supervisors

Comment: I am not aware of any Java feature that works like the Erlang supervisor. This could be uncharted territory, I don't know. But if you learn the Erlang supervisor concept and logic, you could implement something simple and similar for your specific usecase in your Java code. 

Erlang is always so much less code and more stability when compared to Java.

Comment: Thanks alot  please add those comments to the answer so i can mark it as the accepted answer :)

Comment: I think you can mark it as the accepted answer anyway.